# Convert 'Mon Dec 12 10:55:11 UTC 2016' to datetime in Hive

Tags: datetime, hadoop, hive, timestamp, hiveql

I am unable to convert the below string to datetime in Hive.

`Mon Dec 12 10:55:11 UTC 2016`

I have used `date_format('Mon Dec 12 10:55:11 UTC 2016','dd-MM-yyyy')`. But I get `NULL` as a result.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `unix_timestamp(string date, string pattern)` to convert string in  [**given  format**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) to seconds passed from [**Unix Epoch**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC).

Then use `from_unixtime()` to convert to [**required format**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html).

**Demo:**

Your initial format is `'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy'`

Converting to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (default):

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('Mon Dec 12 10:55:11 UTC 2016','EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy'));
```

Returns:

```
2016-12-12 10:55:11
```

Converting to `yyyy-MM-dd`:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('Mon Dec 12 10:55:11 UTC 2016','EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Returns:

```
2016-12-12
```